# Label the INCOMPLETE portion of a Bootstrap Progress Bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I would like to add a label (and color) to both the complete and incomplete portion of a progress bar using [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/). Here is an example:

[image: Hot Rolled Negotiations?]

I know I can set a CSS background for the entire `.progress` element, but how can I add a label to the remaining INCOMPLETE section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a single progress bar, use ["stacked" progress bars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#progress-stacked) that add up to 100%:

```
<h4>Steel Mill Negotiations?</h4>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="21" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:21%">21% Yes</div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="79" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 79%">79% No</div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image: Bootstrap Stacked Progress Bar]